# Prettify csv on github repository

Tags: csv, github

I created a CSV file containing all French song titles which contains a first name in the title. And I had some troubles with GitHub: it can prettify your CSV ([Documentation Github](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/using-files/working-with-non-code-files#rendering-csv-and-tsv-data)), however after some little change I still have this error:

> We can make this file beautiful and searchable if this error is corrected: No commas found in this CSV file in line 0.

The funny part of this error is my CSV starts at line 1. I don't see any errors or problems at first glance.

By the way, if you want to check the CSV directly you can at my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Boutast/French_Names_In_Music/blob/main/French_name_in_music.csv). And you can download it of course, use it for datascience experimentation...

Why isn't GitHub able to prettify my file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using semi-colons (`;`) in your file:

```
﻿Title;Name;Singer;Time;Name_Gender;Singer_Gender
Dans les yeux d'Emilie;Emilie;Joe Dassin;03:44;Female;Male
```

Change them to commas (`,`):

```
﻿Title,Name,Singer,Time,Name_Gender,Singer_Gender
Dans les yeux d'Emilie,Emilie,Joe Dassin,03:44,Female,Male
```